# Solution verification: Show that if $H,K\leq G$ and $[G:K]<\infty$, then $[H:H\cap K]<\infty$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying the following problem and want to see if my solution is correct:

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of the group $G$ and suppose $K$ has finite index in $G$. Prove that $H\cap K$ has finite index in $H$.

Here is how I'm approaching this: Suppose $[G:K]=n$. Then $K$ has $n$ left cosets in $G$, call them $K,g_2K,g_3K,\dots,g_nK$. Now we show that for all $g\in G$, we have that $g(H\cap K)=gH\cap gK$. Suppose $a\in g(H\cap K)$. Then $a=gh$ for some $h\in H\cap K$. This means $a\in gH$ and $a\in gK$, so that $a\in gH\cap gK$. Now if $b\in gH\cap gK$, we find that $b=gh$ for some $h\in H$ and $b=gk$ for some $k\in K$. Thus, $gh=gk$ so that $h=k$. This shows that $h,k\in H\cap K$, meaning $b\in g(H\cap K)$. Since $H\cap K\leq H$, this shows that every coset of $H\cap K$ in $H$ is of the form $gH\cap gK$. Therefore, since there are $n$ possibilities for $gK$, this means there are at most $n$ left cosets of $H\cap K$ in $H$, so that $[H:H\cap K]\leq n<\infty$.

Am I right here? I feel like I might be missing something. It feels a little too easy to jump to the conclusion that this means there are at most $n$ cosets of $H\cap K$ in $H$. I don't know if this would be better reinforced by creating a (possibly injective) mapping between $H/(H\cap K)$ and $G/K$ (where these are the sets of cosets, not necessarily quotient groups). Maybe it could be $g(H\cap K)\mapsto gK$.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: @Shaun thank you, I just added an explanation.

Comment: More thoughts on this: We could even strengthen this to say that up to $n$ of the coset representatives $e,g_2,\dots, g_n$ (that represent distinct cosets) are in $H$, and any coset of $H\cap K$ in $H$ is really of the form $h(H\cap K)=H\cap (hK)$. This means there are up to $n$ representatives $h$ in $H$ that represent distinct cosets of $K$. So then there would be up to $n$ cosets of $H\cap K$ in $H$. Is this a little better?

Comment: @blakedylanmusic yup that is indeed the correct way to fill details. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4690081/861687) is my proof of above exercise. Your proof can be extended to $\infty$ (that is $[G:K]=\infty$). IMO your proof is more elegant than mine.

Comment: @user264745 thank you! I think your solution was much more thorough than mine, but I’m glad to see mine still worked! Thanks for your help!